# Add a space between dot or comma and a letter but with some exceptions

Tags: php, regex, string, spacing, punctuation

I need to do some grammar validation, for example add spaces after dots. Problem is that it shouldn't be done everywhere like in `e.g.` or `www.example.co.` or some more advanced exceptions like `999.77.SA`.

My idea was to use `preg_replace()` and this one works perfectly for everything, but there's no place for exceptions.

```
//add space after a dot 
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=[.,])(?=\p{L}+)/u', ' ',$string);
```

I could try adding those exceptions to the regexp itself, but we have many of those and the expression would be terribly complicated.

I tried also with `preg_match()` or `preg_match_callback()`, but the match array returns only empty strings so that doesn't help.

Example text

```
Hello.This is my example.In some cases space shouldn't be added. Like in e.g. or www.example.com or 88.ASD
```

Should be changed to:

```
Hello. This is my example. In some cases space shouldn't be added. Like in e.g. or www.example.com or 88.ASD
```

Do you have some idea how to do this the cleanest way?

Comment: I feel like this question needs clarity: Which kinds of `.` should match, and which should not? Without a concrete definition, it's impossible to know when not to add a space.

Comment: This is a NLP-hard problem. A regex probably won't be sufficient for such kind of task.

Comment: It should add space everywhere unless it's explicitly whitelisted by me. So my whitelist could be an array of regex expressions where I'd add "e.g.", "www.{something}", "{number}.{letter}" and so on

Comment: And even then with a whitelist, there could be issues. If you're coming up with any solution with regex, it's unlikely to be a reliable one. Yet that's just my take.

Comment: Then perhaps you can start from here: [`(?:cases where you don't want it to match, separated by pipes)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=[.,])(?=\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/Fzt3lY/1). See [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) for explanation.

Comment: Are you willing to maintain full list of TLDs in you whitelist? So that `example.com, example.pn, example.ru and example.co.uk` are not split by it?

Comment: @markalex in the worst case scenario - we could.

Comment: It will be English text only, so I don't need to worry about other ones. Also it doesn't need to be perfect - some human will check it after anyway, I just want to make it as easy as possible for him, try to minimize things he needs to check.

Comment: Maybe some idea would be to run preg match twice: once with dots and one with exceptions. If position in text of both matches, then don't replace it

Comment: With assumptions 1. Only English. 2. Sentence starts with upper. 3. Any sequence of only upper after dot considered as abbreviation: [`[.,]\K(?=[A-Z])(?![A-Z]+\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/OxN2c5/2). And it still wouldn't work for `77.I`

Comment: Or maybe a bit more adequate to commas: [`\.\K(?=[A-Z])(?:(?![A-Z]+\b)|(?=I\b))|,\K(?!\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/OxN2c5/3)

Comment: I think solution proposed by @InSync looks promising. I'll test it

Answer (score 0):

This task is not solvable in general way with simple regex (or even very complicated one).

Problem is that without semantic understanding of sentence there is no way to classify if `.` is part of abbreviation or separator of sentences.

Take for example something similar to your example: `77.I`: depending on the context it could be abbreviation `position with code 77.I named "Other"`. Or Parts of two sentences. `Elm street 77.I leave there`.

---

Also, consider that `.` may have additional meanings in other languages. For example, in Latvian `2.A` means "second A", and while space there might be acceptable, there is no clear reason for it to appear.